# Is it possible to use gensim word2vec model in deeplearning4j.word2vec?

Tags: java, gensim, word2vec, deeplearning4j

I'm new to deeplearning4j, i want to make sentence classifier using words vector as input for the classifier. 
I was using python before, where the vector model was generated using gensim, and i want to use that model for this new classifier. 
Is it possible to use gensim's word2vec model in deeplearning4j.word2vec and how i can do that?

Comment: Please ask this on our Gitter channel. https://gitter.im/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j There are 4300 DL4J users there.

Comment: thanks, i'll try asking there

Comment: Did you get an answer? If so, could you post it here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it's possible since Word2Vec implementation defines a standard to structure its model.

To do this:

1. Using *gensim*, save the model **compatible with Word2Vec implementation**:

   ```
   w2v_model.wv.save_word2vec_format("path/to/w2v_model.bin", binary=True)
   ```
2. From *DL4J*, load the same pre-trained model:

   ```
   Word2Vec w2vModel = WordVectorSerializer.readWord2VecModel("path/to/w2v_model.bin");
   ```

In fact, you could test the model in both codes and you should see the same results, for instance:

With gensim:

```
print(w2v_model.most_similar("love"))
print(w2v_model.n_similarity(["man"], ["king"]))
```

And with DL4J:

```
System.out.println(w2vModel.wordsNearest("love", 10));
System.out.println(w2vModel.similarity("man", "king"));
```